# Android how to trace that the user visited the page in a browser,

Tags: android, service

I want create a service, which check web-sites user visited. So, I have an URL of site or web-page, now my service should catch when a user comes to this page and remember this page as visited. So, the service should be all the same, which browser does the person uses. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Would you want any third-party app to be able to track what you browse on your phone?

Comment: I want to create the app, which detect how many times user visited some site. It would have been with the consent of the user.